# Grouping child items and displaying parent sum

Tags: sas

I have the following table

```
+-------+--------+---------+
| group | item   |  value  |
+-------+--------+---------+
|   1   |   a    |   10    |
|   1   |   b    |   20    |
|   2   |   b    |   30    |
|   2   |   c    |   40    |
+-------+--------+---------+
```

I would like to group the table by `group`, insert the grouped sum into `value`, and then ungroup:

```
+-------+--------+
| item  | value  |
+-------+--------+
|   1   |   30   |
|   a   |   10   |
|   b   |   20   |
|   2   |   70   |
|   b   |   30   |
|   c   |   40   |
+-------+--------+
```

The purpose of the result is to interpret the first column as items a and b belonging to group 1 with sum 30 and items b and c belonging to group 2 with sum 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that both `group` and `item` are character variables

```
data have;
infile datalines firstobs=4 dlm='|';
input group $ item $ value;
datalines;
+-------+--------+---------+
| group | item   |  value  |
+-------+--------+---------+
|   1   |   a    |   10    |
|   1   |   b    |   20    |
|   2   |   b    |   30    |
|   2   |   c    |   40    |
+-------+--------+---------+
;

data want (keep=group value);
    do _N_=1 by 1 until (last.group);
        set have;
        by group;
        v + value;
    end;
    value = v;output;v=0;
    do _N_=1 to _N_;
        set have;
        group = item;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Such a data transformation can be indicative of a reporting requirement more than a useful data structure for downstream processing.  `Proc REPORT` can create output in the form desired.

```
data have;
infile datalines;
input group $ item $ value @@; datalines;
 1 a 10   1 b 20   2 b 30   2 c 40  
;

proc report data=have;
  column group item value;
  define group / order order=data noprint;
  break before group / summarize;
  compute item;
    if missing(item) then item=group;
  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]